# Issue with the cocos2d game start

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android, revmob

i have developed cocos2d game app, here when the game starts the targets starts falling from top to bottom, there is no issues here, after adding code for revmob(ad page), targets are not falling in the screen, i had checked with the revmob code everything is correct, but dont know where i have gone wrong, please look at my issue, thanks in advance:)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    // hide titlebar of application
    // must be before setting the layout
  this.requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    // hide statusbar of Android
    // could also be done later
  this.getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
  this.getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON );
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT );

    mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
    revmob = RevMob.start(this, APPLICATION_ID);
    displayRevMob();

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);

 }

public void displayRevMob(){
    revmob.showFullscreen(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add displayRevMob() method in onstart method of the activity rather in oncreate.